# MQ .NET Assemblies MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY Ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, mq

I'm currently working with the MQ .NET assemblies and am attempting to read queue depths of various queues for a monitoring application.  We have the code working in Java, but our new application is in C# and it would be preferable to keep all this logic in the same application.

From what I've heard online, .NET assemblies ignore `MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY` and instead use the user ID of whoever is running the application.  Is there really no way to override this?  This seems a very strange feature/bug.  I know that `MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY` is supposed to influence how the `UserID` is inferred, but whether I set to `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED` or `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT`, I see the same ID going up in Wireshark and get the same error back (`MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED`).  Has anyone else found a workaround for this fairly large issue?

```
properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userId);
properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "");

// create connection
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MQ .NET client (or for that matter MQ C client also) version prior to v8, the user id set by the application is not sent to the queue manager. Instead logged in user id is passed to queue manager for authentication. This is a known behavior of MQ versions prior v8.

You can develop and use what is known as `security exit` to perform user authentication. A security exit performs username and password authentication against a repository, such as the local operating system on the MQ server, or an LDAP repository.

You can also use SSL/TLS if that's suitable to you. Otherwise you can move up to use MQ v8 to make use of the out of the box user id/password authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Shashi.  Is this based on the version of the assemblies/client that I am running or the version of MQ on the server? The MQ version is 7.05, which I have no control over, but on the client side I am using 8.0.0.4, and the issue is still occurring.

Comment: Well, thats a bummer.  But thank you for finally settling this for me!  Looks like I will be doing this in Java.

Comment: I am using MQ 9.0 but still facing same issue. The USER_ID_PROPERTY is ignored. Am I missing any setting in MQ ?